# How to completely remove a predicate in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, predicate

I have the predicate `color/2` with the following facts:

```
color(omlette, yellow).
color(tomato, red).
color(cucumber, green).
...
```

Now I want to completely remove it from the system, i.e. I want `current_predicate(color/2)` to fail.
However, even if I `retractall(color(_, _))`, and indeed all facts relating to `color` are removed, `current_predicate(color/2)` would still succeed.

How can I make it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [abolish/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=abolish/1) to completely remove all the clauses of a procedure and its attributes:

```
abolish(color/2).
```

Depending on your prolog processor you may have to indicate that the procedure is dynamic, in your example with

```
:-dynamic(color/2).
```